# At least how many consecutive numbers should be taken?

Tags: abstract-algebra, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

### Problem Statement :

At least how many consecutive positive integers should be multiplied so that the product is divisible by $5040$ ?

This problem should be solved using algebra.

### My attempt :

Let the multiplication of n consecutive numbers is divisible by 5040 . So according to question :

x*(x+1)(x+2)$\ldots$(x+n-1)=5040*m

How can I find the value of n ? Please help me .

Comment: In the problem statement, perhaps you should specify that the consecutive numbers start at 1. Otherwise any sequence of length 1 whose single term is divisible by 5040 would work.

Comment: Consecutive numbers not starting at 1 also work .

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you asking for a number $n$ such that the product of any $n$ consecutive numbers is divisible by $7!$ ?

Comment: At least how many consecutive numbers should be taken so that the multiplication of these numbers is divisible by 5040 ?

Comment: Just restating the same question in the same words is not going to clarify anything.  I assume you mean what I said in my prior comment, no?

Comment: Anyway, assuming I have the question right, guessing $n=7$ seems natural.  Can you prove that this works?  Certainly the answer can not be smaller than $7$.

Comment: What is wrong with the sequence 5040? Then the answer is one. Do you see what our issue is?

Comment: I don't understand why you decline to clarify the question.  You can see from the comments and from the posted solution that nobody is sure what you mean.  I think my interpretation is correct, but I note that it differs from the interpretation used in the posted solution.

Comment: I have edited the question . Please see the update and let me know .

Comment: Again the answer is one (as phrased) because we can take $x$ to be 5040.

Comment: Well, the edit helps a bit though as stated $n$ will depend on $x$.  I am sticking to my interpretation, which is that you want the least $n$ that works for all starting values $x$ and I have posted a solution to that question below.

Comment: Is my answer right now that the question has been edited? Frankly I am still unsure what is being asked of me.

Comment: I want to find out the value of n by algebric method .

Comment: Perhaps language is a barrier here.  Could you review the two posted solutions and tell us if either of us are answering the question you had in mind?

Comment: $n = 4$ while letting $m = 1$?

Comment: @IccheGuri ami proshno ta thik bujhlam na. Ektu bujhaite parben?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is phrased poorly and it is not clear what is intended.  I believe the following is relevant:

Claim:  the product of any $7$ consecutive natural numbers is divisible by $7!$ and no number smaller than $7$ has this property.

Proof:  It is clear that no number smaller than $7$ works as $6!$ is not divisible by $7$, let alone $7!$, and it is (visibly) the product of $6$ natural numbers.

To see that $7$ has the desired property, let $m$ denote the start of the consecutive block and we remark that $$\binom {m+6}{7}=\frac {(m+6)(m+5)\cdots (m)}{7!}\in \mathbb N$$ is an integer, hence the desired result.

Comment: I have edited the question . Please see the update and let me know

Comment: I think you missed the word consecutive.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan  What do you mean?  $(m+6)\cdots (m)$ is the product of $7$ consecutive integers starting with $m$.

Comment: No I meant that in the _Claim_ section you missed the word consecutive. Your proof is perfect.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan  Oh!  Of course you are right.  Thanks.  Corrected.

Comment: Is it permitted that I communicate in any language other than English. Ichche Guri is Bengali, as am I so I think I can solve the problem by communicating in Bengali.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan  I think that's a great (and generous) idea.  At the end, it would be a service to the site if you would summarize the results, or just edit the post according to what you learn.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I would have done so but was unsure if it was permitted or not.

Answer (score 1):

I personally believe that you need only one number: $5040$, but I assume that is not the kind of answer you want.

Algebraically: 
$n = 5040$

The next best is four consecutive integers:
Let $x$ be the smallest integer:
$x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)= 5040$
I would prefer graphing it but here goes the algebraic way:
$x^4 + 6 x^3 + 11 x^2 + 6 x = 5040$
Solving this gives: 
$x = 7, x= -10, x= \frac 32 i (\sqrt(31) +i),  x = -\frac 32 i (\sqrt(31) - i)$
$x = 7$ is a valid answer as $7*8*9*10 = 5040$

$\therefore$ Four is the (second) least number of consecutive positive integers whose product is $5040$.

$n = 7$ is the least value iff (if and only if) $x = 1$.

Comment: The answer is n = 7 .

Comment: $n = 4$ is also valid, as is $n = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

The least product which is divisible by $5040$ is $5040$ itself. So, the problem is saying to determine a set of consecutive integer numbers whose product (product of all the numbers in that set) is $5040$.and we have to determine the number of the elements in that set.

Let, the starting number be $x$.

and there are $n$ consecutive numbers we need to multiply to make $5040$.

So, $$x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3).....(x+n-2)(x+n-1)=5040...................(1)$$
Again we know, the product of n consecutive numbers is must divisible by $n!$ Which is the least number.

So,$$ n! = 5040…..........(2)$$

$$\implies n=7$$
If we put $n=7$ in equation (1) then we get, $x=1$.

So,the answer is we need to multiply at least $7$ consecutive numbers starting from $1$ to get $5040$